# Popup Javascript não funciona no IE11

Tags: javascript, html

Após migração para o windows 10 e IE11 o meu popup parou de funcionar.
Não sei dizer o que é, pesquisei e nada encontrei. Nas máquinas com windows 7 e IE7,8 continua funcionando normalmente.
Importante os dados dos inputs precisam ser postados para o popup.

Segue código;

**JAVASCRIPT**

```
function target_popup(form) {   
    window.open("", "formpopup", "width=600, height=260, top=300, left=130"); //me parece que o problema está aqui.
    form.target = "formpopup";
}
```

**HTML**

```
<form id="form" action="local.php" method="POST" onsubmit="target_popup(this)">
   <input type="text" name="date" id="date" />
   <input type="text" name="nome" id="nome" />
   <input type="submit" value="SUBMETER" />
</form>
```

**ALGUNS TESTES**

Após inserir as urls manualmente o popup abre;

```
//abre o site do google
window.open("http://www.google.com", "formpopup", "width=600, height=260, top=300, left=130");
//abre "http://local.php" inexistente
window.open("http://local.php", "formpopup", "width=600, height=260, top=300, left=130");
//abre "http://local.php" inexistente
window.open("//local.php", "formpopup", "width=600, height=260, top=300, left=130");
```

Já as urls abaixo **não funcionam**;

```
window.open("http://server:porta/local/arquivo.php", "formpopup", "width=600, height=260, top=300, left=130");
window.open("local/arquivo.php", "formpopup", "width=600, height=260, top=300, left=130");
window.open("arquivo.php", "formpopup", "width=600, height=260, top=300, left=130");
window.open("\\arquivo.php", "formpopup", "width=600, height=260, top=300, left=130");
```

Como conclusão me parece que o IE11 só aceita o endereço com http:// ou // porém não aceita subdiretórios e o endereço deve ter um .algumacoisa, testes fora disso não funcionaram

Comment: O que é essa variável `w`?

Comment: Estranho. Se está abrindo no IE7 e 8 e não no IE11, essas variáveis `w` e `h` estão vindo de algum código incompatível com o IE11. Teria que postar na pergunta o código que trata dessas variáveis para podermos analisar uma mudança compatível com esses 3 navegadores em comum.

Comment: Fiz alguns testes e não me parece ser a variável w, ela realmente esta vindo de outro lugar mas ela recebe apenas um número inteiro, retirei ela para não confundir, fiz alguns testes interessantes vou postar na pergunta.

Comment: Pois eh... tirando essas variáveis, a popup abre normalmente aqui no meu IE11.

Comment: O meu mesmo tirando não vai. Inseri os teste na pergunta.

Comment: Apenas como garantia, aperta F12 no IE, vai na aba Emulation e verifica qual modo de documento está.

Comment: No console diz modo de documento 7. Na Emulação também está no 7. Troquei para o 8 e o Console informa na linha do window.open "Não há suporte para esta interface".

Comment: Ainda não vi qual é o erro. Testei todos os exemplos que vc postou e todos abriram a popup.

Comment: A maquina esta sem acesso adm, pode influenciar ?

Comment: Testei em uma máquina com acesso adm e funcionou.. Acho que tem a ver com permissão. Vou dar uma olhada e se realmente for isso excluir a pergunta.